# Flatten scala tuple with Set

Tags: scala

I have the following Tuple

`(a,b) = (String, Set[String])` and I want to convert it to an array/list of `(a,b(1)),(a,(b2))` etc..

I tried a few ways with flatMap, always ending with a list of b1,b2 but not with a tuple of (a,some b).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variant, just mapping directly over the Set:

```
scala> val t = ("x", Set("a","b","c"))

scala> t._2.map((t._1, _))

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] 
      = Set((x,a), (x,b), (x,c))
```

In real code, I'd probably do it as follows to avoid all the `_1`, `_2` ugliness, e.g:

```
t match {case (a,b) => b.map((a, _))}
```

(and add a `toList` on the end of any of these if you really need a List rather than a Set as your final output)

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val (a, b) = ("hello", Set(1, 2, 3))
a: String = hello
b: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> b.to[List].map(e => (a, e))
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((hello,1), (hello,2), (hello,3))
```

Just remember that `Set` doesn't preserve order.

Edit(usage in transformations):

```
scala> case class Movie(i: String, g: Set[String], t: String, y: String)

defined class Movie

scala> val movies = List(Movie("a", Set("a", "b", "c"), "a", "a"), Movie("b", Set("d", "e", "f"), "b", "b"))

movies: List[Movie] = List(Movie(a,Set(a, b, c),a,a), Movie(b,Set(d, e, f),b,b))

scala> movies.map{case Movie(i, g, t, y) => (t, g.to[List])}.map{case (str, list) => list.map(e => (str, e))}
res1: List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List((a,a), (a,b), (a,c)), List((b,d), (b,e), (b,f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A for comprehension provides a neat syntax for this case; let

```
val (k,s) = ("z", Set("a","b","c"))

for (v <- s) yield (k,v)
```

Also consider `zipAll` like this,

```
k.zipAll(s,"z","z")
```

where string `k` is treated as a sequence, and we pad unequal size collections with `"z"`.